# In $Ax=b$. If $A$ is not invertible there are no solutions or infinity. How to determine what the case is?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I learnt that for the equation:
$Ax=b$

There is one solution if $A$ is invertible.

But if $A$ is singular there are infinity solutions or no solutions at all.

If $A$ is singular is it possible to determine whether there are no solutions or infinity solutions?

Comment: You must add the condition that $A$ is a square matrix for these conditions to make sense ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linear equations given by $Ax = b$ have a solution if and only if $\operatorname{rank}(A|b) = \operatorname{rank}(A)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2090742/linear-equations-given-by-ax-b-have-a-solution-if-and-only-if-operatorname)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the general theory says that the solutions exist iff

$$
rk(A)=rk(\bar{A}),
$$

where $\bar{A}$ is the matrix with the additional column $b$ appended to it (it is called the augmented matrix).

Comment: Why the downvote? Isn't this correct?

Comment: To me the Question is how-to-tell, not yes or no.  I'm not the down voter however.

Comment: I have no idea - looks correct to me!

Comment: @hardmath I thought this answers the how-to-tell question: compare the ranks. Whatever, though.

Comment: Sure, that is true.  I'd say a few words about row reduction but that's only one perspective.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, to examine the size of the solution set of a system of linear equations, we look at the rank of the coefficient matrix compared with the rank of the augmented matrix.

Let $A$ be the coefficient matrix of a system of linear equations in $n$ unknowns and $\mathbf{b}$ be the vector of constants. If $\text{rank}(A|\mathbf{b}) = \text{rank}(A) = n$ then we have a single unique solution. If you put a square matrix into reduced row-echelon form and it has rank $n$ then the reduced row-echelon form of that matrix is $\mathbb{I}_n$ the identity matrix, which is equivalent to having a unique solution to the system.

If $\text{rank}(A|\mathbf{b}) = \text{rank}(A) < n$ then there are infinitely many solutions to the system. In this case, we see that the row-echelon form of the matrix has a row of zeroes at the bottom and this means that at least one of the variables is a $\textit{free variable}$.

If $\text{rank}(A|\mathbf{b}) > \text{rank}(A)$ then there are no solutions. This is easy to see, since there will be a row of zeroes in the row echelon form of $A$ but a row of the form $[0\ 0 \ 0 \cdot\cdot\cdot\ c]$ in $(A|\mathbf{b})$ with $c \neq 0$, which corresponds to a linear equation of the form

$$0a_1 + 0a_2 + 0a_3 + \dots + 0a_n = c$$

which, of course, is nonsense.

Comment: Not to discredit your answer in any way, but do you have any idea why was my answer downvoted? Isn't it the same thing?

Comment: I agree with the comments below your post. Perhaps the lack of detail was the reason for the downvote. I am unsure why people are downvoting it!

Answer (score 2):

A simple and fast answer is that if $b$ is in the space spanned by the column of $A$, there will be infinite solutions. Otherwise, there is no solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your question's title isn't logical, but see Proposition 3.38 in [Kuldeep Singh's *Linear Algebra: Step by Step*](https://maths-for-all.co.uk/linear-algebra/)
(2013) on p. 265.  Typo is "Exercises 3.6" that ought "Exercise 3.6.14" on p 268.

[image]